# Efficiently getting all completed tasks

Tags: asana, asana-api

For an application I need all the user's recently completed tasks (recent meaning the last 7 days in this case). I've got it working now, but it's extremely inefficient and in the API reference I can't see a better way to do it.

What I currently need to do is get the current user (https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/users/me), iterate through the user's workspaces and call https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks?workspace=workspaceId&assignee=me&completed_since=sevenDaysAgo for each workspace. This gives me the compact task data for all completed tasks for all projects in that workspace, and also all uncompleted tasks for all projects in that workspace. Since I only need the completed tasks, I need to filter the uncompleted tasks out of that list. However, the compact task data doesn't include the "completed" property. To figure out if a task is completed or uncompleted, I need to get the full task data, which means a call to https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/taskId *per task*.

Say I have two workspaces that each have three projects, and each project has on average 100 completed tasks and 200 uncompleted tasks. That means 1 + 2 + (2 * 3) + (2 * 3 * 300) = a whopping 1809 API requests. Apart from this being very slow, it's also a large hit on the Asana servers.

Is there a way to do this more efficiently? Only getting compact task data for completed tasks would go a long way. Getting it in one call would be even better: how does Asana itself do this in My Tasks > View: Recently Completed Tasks, for instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Asana dev here) Have you considered using `?opt_fields=completed` in your initial `GET /tasks` request? You can specifically request any fields you want, see the [Input/Output option docs](https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/input-output-options), and of course see [Task docs](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks) for a reference on available fields. So if you really just want the name (for instance) you could request `?opt_fields=completed,name`.

Sadly, you will need to do the filtering out of incomplete tasks on your side.

Comment: This is awesome, I completely missed the opt_fields parameter. This solves my problem instantly, I now no longer have to call /tasks/taskId anymore at all: I simply select all the fields I needed in the /tasks?workspace= call. This reduces the number of calls to 1 for the /me call and 1 per workspace, which isn't bad at all. Also, tasks now load lightning fast instead of dribbling in. Thanks!